Network configuration error occurs when deploying PieCloudDB on Ubuntu
I recently tried to deploy PieCloudDB Database Community Edition 2.14 on a single-node cluster using ubuntu server 20.04, but an error related to network configuration occurred during the installation process.
Is there any extra changes needed on the configuration files?

Well, my IP configuration is incorrect. Deploying PieCloudDB Database on a single node requires configuring three IPs, I have to configure the secondary IPs of two network segments on the ubuntu01 machine.
I corrected it to the following:
   hosts:
    - {hostname: ubuntu01, ip: 172.x.x.101, secondary_ips: [172.x.x.111, 172.x.x.121], user: root, password: "******"}
   cluster_roles:
     control_plane:
     - ubuntu01
     data_plane:
     - ubuntu01
     s3:
     - ubuntu01

Then edit the configuration file 00-installer-config.yaml of the "ubuntu01" node in the /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml directory, add two IP addresses in the same network segment to the configuration, and then execute netplan apply , the command will take effect.
